# Connecting to wireless at work with a personal phones

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone

We all have personal data on our phones from Facebook, emails and websites.
Is connecting our phone to work's wireless alright or it is recommended to forget about saving some data usage on the phone plan and just use the carrier's network?

Comment: This is a very broad question. What do you mean by 'is it alright to connect your phones to the work network'. Well it would depend on the IT policy. What your own concern would be in doing this (data storage) and what issues would arise from using your phone plan which could very well suffer from similar issues. Can you give us a specific issue you want addressing here.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams by common sense! I meant to ask ok now do they have acces to my Instagram? to my Facebook? can they see what have I visited on the phone?! etc...

Comment: Does your company log network connections? Probably. Can they see your passwords and personal user data? No. Should this be a problem to you? Only if your company has a policy of which websites are allowed to be accessed on their network, in which case they should block them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That all depends on your company and its policies.

Where I work, I have setup a second wireless network for personal phones and tablets etc which is completely outside our work firewall and logging. This way people do not have to use their plans, but also they do not get logged on the work network.

Comment: yeah exactly, we have the same. A public wireless that they give us the password to it and a work network, for example Facebook is blocked on work network but is open on public wireless network. So my concern is it is safe for my own privacy and private stuff to connect to that public wireless on my phone? or just use the carrier's data plan ?

Comment: @DevWannaBe | This is a very different question to the one you posted. Now you are discussing security on a public access network. Can you edit your question and be specific about what you are asking here.

Comment: thanks for the editing help, my English is rubbish apparently, and also thanks for accepting my answer.